# INSERTs and UPDATEs in ruby/rails using PostgreSQL functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, postgis, squeel, rgeo

I'm using activerecord-postgis-adapter and squeel in a geo oriented application. Fetching data using various queries based on find and where is working fine and squeel allows me to use PostgreSQL/PostGIS functions to query based on spatial functions and datatypes.

However, I can't figure out how to access similar functions when performing INSERTs and UPDATEs. Say I want to do something in the line of:

```
UPDATE object SET raster = ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1,5),10),150, 150, '2BUI') 
where id = 12345;
```

How could I perform such a query? Squeel doesn't even seem to have support for other queries than SELECTs.

In a perfect world I would even want to have Rgeo's datatypes automatically converted when used in UPDATE queries, just like with where queries.

I am aware that I can fall back to

> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

, but would rather avoid that unless someone tells me it's the only way.

-ra

Comment: For something so database specific I would go with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.

Answer (score 1):

you could create a connection to the database per model you're working with. one method you can run is the `select_value` method, there are others:

```
sql = "UPDATE object SET raster = ST_AsRaster(ST_Buffer(ST_Point(1,5),10),150, 150, '2BUI') where id = 12345;"
conn = ModelName.connection
conn.select_value(sql)
```

should run your command

see this post by Daniel Azuma for more about this one: http://blog.daniel-azuma.com/archives/216

you could conceivably put this type of code in migrations. In fact its probably a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

`update_all` accepts an array param, so that you could e.g. do:

```
SomeClass
  .where(id: 123)
  .limit(1)
  .update_all(
    ["some_field = some_pg_func(?, ?)", "some", "values"]
  )
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all